# Pass Entire InfoPath Form to Web Service (Not Submitting)

Tags: web-services, infopath2010

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that queries a web service. The web service is expecting the entire InfoPath form as an XML string parameter. By an XML string I mean the string on the format

```
<my:myFields xmlns:my=...>
    <my:Name>UserName</my:Name>
    ...
</my:myFields>
```

The web service will then process the string and return a result to the InfoPath form.

I have tried to pass the root element, ".", but at the web service end I am receiving the values only formatted by \r\n and \t. Any idea on how to pass the XML tags and the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround by passing the list name and the form name to a web service. The web service, which is hosted in SharePoint, will then get the XML of the form.

Here is the code for reference:

```
public class InfoPathHelper
{
    private string _listName;
    private string _fileUrl;

    public InfoPathHelper(string listName, string fileName)
    {
        _listName = listName;
        _fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}.xml", listName, fileName); 
    }

    public string GetFormXml()
    {
        using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
        {
            SPList lib = web.Lists[_listName];
            SPFile file = lib.RootFolder.Files[_fileUrl];
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(file.OpenBinaryStream());
            return doc.OuterXml;
        }
    }
}
```