# InfoPath Send Entire Form When Using a Receive Connection

Tags: web-services, infopath2010, data-connections

I'm trying to configure an **InfoPath form** with a **receiving dataconnection** (SOAP). When using a submit connection the option "**Entire form** (xml document, including processing instructions)" is available. But I need this for a receiving connection as parameter.

Using `MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().OuterXml` to grab the form XML does not work as parameter. The webservice does not get any data.

I found this topic [Pass Entire InfoPath Form to Web Service (Not Submitting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948742/pass-entire-infopath-form-to-web-service-not-submitting), what covers the problem for an InfoPath form that works on a list.

I even catched the network traffic for a submit dataconnection sending the entire form using the IE developer tools, but there was no XML string ...

Is there another possibility to pass the entire form as parameter for a receive connection in the same way as it is done for a submit connection?